# Miscoloured tiles in ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, tiles

I have a tile layer created on ArcGIS for Server 10.3. most of the tiles have worked out fine, but I have a number of tiles that are odd colours. I have tried rebuilding the cache, but the odd tiles are still there.

The aerial in the tiles is four separate mrSid files.

What is causing the odd colours and how do I replace them?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I mosaicked the mrSid images in a mosaic dataset.  I added the mosaic to the map instead of the four mrSid images.  Then I rebuilt all the tiles.  This has fixed the regions shown above, and I have not yet noticed any others.

My suspicion is that the tiling process in ArcGIS has difficulty with overlapping mrSid images.